# Zend project not working on XAMPP

Tags: zend-framework, xampp

I have just created zend project on my local machine. but when I try to run it in the browser, it just loads for at least a minute and then shows this error.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /opt/lampp/htdocs/launchmind/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 815
```

**It displays the same error with some other line number on some other file every time I reload the page.**

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have some firewall issue that causes the script to timeout. Check connections from you local machine to all the database hosts in the config and/or webservices and/or other involved servers.

Here are few tips:

1. Monitor xampp `error_log` and `/var/log/messages`...
2. Since it's local server, disable the firewall temporarily to see if the problem is with your local firewall (preventing outgoing connection) or remote server firewall (preventing incoming connection). On RHEL use `sudo service iptables stop` or `/etc/init.d/iptables stop`
3. if you have very time consuming tasks in your app (very unlikely) then you can try to bump up the max execution time either by modifying `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` (somewhere there) or set max execution time in your app config `phpSettings.max_execution_time = 60` or use `ini_set` in bootstrap

Hope this helps.