# zend framework installation on xampp

Tags: zend-framework

I am completely begginer with ZEND FRAMEWORK. I tried to install but was getting some error.

As I go with the zf@1 version installation.

1. I extracted my folder to the path. `C:\xampp\php` naming it as zendframework.
2. I edited my php.ini file's include_path as `include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\php\zendframework\library"`
3. Restarted Server.
4. Run cmd with path C:\xampp\php\ (where my exact zf.bat files)
5. Running command `zf show version` ended with zf error that my zend framework should be in include path.

   - How to resolve this error?
   - Is issue is resolved my next command `zf create project zend_blog` is correct?
   - How to create project with zf1 and zf 2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Follow the given Instruction Below.


  • Go to ‘My Computer’ > Properties > Advanced Tab > Environment Variables. 
   Environment Variables box will open, View SYSTEM VARIABLES, 
    scroll the list to ’ PATH ‘ > double click ’ PATH ‘ .
      Add the following line to the end of the PATH  C:\xampp\php
    Zend Framework
  • Extract the Zend Framework files to C:\xampp\php\zf.
   •    Edit the php.ini file. You will find it at C:\xampp\php\php.ini. 
    Find the line that says ’ include_path ’ and edit the line: 
 Windows: “\path1;\path2″
  include_path = “C:\xampp\php\zf\library”
  • Open a shell and cd to C:\xampp\htdocs folder and type this:
    C:\xampp\htdocs>C:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\bin\zf.bat create project    testproject(project name)


  • Now Copy the Zend Folder from your ZendFramework folder ( C:\xampp\php\zf/library /Zend) into the library folder of your new test project ( C:\xampp\htdocs\testproject\library\Zend
```

Answer (score 0):

it has nothing to do with XAMPP. Something is not configured right or not correct privileges.

See these:

- [Setting up the CLI tool on Windows](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html#zend.tool.framework.clitool.setup-windows)
- Also, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913649/zend-project-not-working-on-xampp/13918250#13918250)
- You can also consider using NetBeans IDE, it has great support for ZF tool. [Check it out this tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/zend-framework-screencast.html).

Comment: When I tried using netbeans I ended with following errors `"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: check there tutorials: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html and http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the zend framework path and the php.exe path into your [windows path variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) in order to run commands from the command line. This is important in ZF1 so that Zend_Tool will work at the command line or in Netbeans or other Ide's.